# Can't automate Edit Control and List box using TestStack.White

Tags: c#, c++, mfc, white-framework

I have an application written with Visual Studio 2012 professional in C++ MFC. Currently I want to create some automation scripts using the TestStack.White framework written in C#.

I can't control the List Box and Edit Control. 
I am using spy++. The edit control is nested inside the Group Box and I'm not able to check the automation ID.

Example of my code

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(ExeSourceFile);
application = Application.AttachOrLaunch(psi);
mainWindow = application.GetWindow(SearchCriteria.ByText(applicationName), InitializeOption.NoCache);
```

Where ExeSourceFile is the path to the application.

This is the way that I tried. Where IDC_Edit is the ID from designer.

```
TextBox TextObj = mainWindow.Get<TextBox>     (SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("IDC_Edit"));
```

1. How do I control the "List Box" check/count row data (currently I am using the up and down arrows as a work around)?
2. How do I control the "Edit Control" inside Group Box (currently as work a around I am using the tab key to change focus)?

I tried to get the MFC controls by ID but it failed. Should I use a tool other than Spy++ or another framework?

Edit:

Here is Screnshot form inspect.
[image: Inspect screenshot]

I tried with id "1221" and also "0x1221" but without success.

Comment: [GroupBox Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368766.aspx) do not implement any sort of nesting. There is no difference with respect to automation whether the Edit control lies inside a GroupBox or not. If you need to see the accessible tree of objects, use the [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521.aspx) tool instead. I assume that TestStack White uses the same accessible tree for automation.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this testing framework, but who does the conversion from the text "IDC_Edit" to its numeric value?

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot of the control's properties from inspect.

Comment: I will take a look at this when I get home. It will take me a little bit to get an MFC application setup though since I have never used it before. Thanks for the screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

I used the MFC wizard to make a visual studio looking application and added a edit control to the properties window so I could test the edit control. I was not able to add a group box because a CGroupBox does not exist from what I could tell. If you could please provide some code for how the group box is implemented I might be able to add that to my answer.

With that out of the way hopefully I can answer some of your questions.

Here is the console application I wrote in C# to automate a "List Box" and a "Edit" control.

```
 using System;
 using TestStack.White;
 using TestStack.White.UIItems;
 using TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders;
 using TestStack.White.UIItems.ListBoxItems;

 namespace ConsoleApplication1
 {
     public class Program
     {
         public static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             var application = Application.Attach("MFCApplication1");
             var window = application.GetWindow("MFCApplication11 - MFCApplication1");

             //Edit Control
             var propertyPane = window.Get<Panel>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("150"));
             var edit = propertyPane.Get<TextBox>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("1"));

             //Type this text into the edit control
             edit.Text = "Hello World";

             //List View
             var output = window.Get<Panel>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("149"));
             var list = output.Get<ListBox>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("2"));

             //Output the count of how many rows exist
             Console.Out.WriteLine(list.Items.Count);

             //Select the second row
             list.Items[1].Select();
         }
     }
 }
```

Here is a image of the application I tested with the controls I automated highlighted.

[image: MFC Example Application]

Comment: TextBox start working when I turn off Visual Studio Exception. I am not able to select any line of List probably because it's drawn. With other list everything works fine. Thank You for Your suggestions.